# Perl GUI Debugger - OSX

Tags: macos, perl, debugging

I'm running into some trouble with my perl scripts, what is a good perl debugger I can use?  I've tried using the perl -d but it doesn't seem to read the script properly. Iv'e used gdb with c and eclipse with c. but I'm finding it hard to find a Perl debugger with a GUI.
Any suggestions??

Thank you.

Comment: I do not think such a question is offtopic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ptkdb](http://search.cpan.org/~aepage/Devel-ptkdb-1.1091/ptkdb.pm) is my favourite. It runs off the Tk library so you should just need to

```
sudo cpan Tk
sudo cpan Devel::ptkdb
```

Then run your script with

```
perl -d:ptkdb script.pl
```

with anything you want to pass in after the script

---

I just tried this with my Mavericks Mac and ran into a few issues. (missing X) It has worked previously for me. YMMV

Comment: Thank you so much. Dont know why it was down voted but thanks for the suggestion.